# change captcha without a mouse

Tags: bug, captcha

Just noticed that while typing my last question... I got the Are You a Human page, with the captcha.

I couldn't read one of the words for nothing. And there was no way to focus the reload button (or any of the 3 buttons on the right of the image) with tab. Also I know clicking the image changes it on mobile, but there was no way to focus it either.

Am I forced to just hit enter and reload the page when I don't have a mouse?

Comment: I'm going to check on this.